# How to parse nested Object model in retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Here is what we get from our API

```
{
    "result": true,
    "message": "Login successful",
    "objects": [
        {
            "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have 2 model for this json.

First is our **base model** (it is **static** for each endpoint) :

```
data class APIResultModel(
    @SerializedName("result")
    var result: Boolean? = false,

    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String? = "",

    @SerializedName("objects")
    var objects: Any?
)
```

Second is our **nested model** class (which is **different** for each endpoint)

```
data class UserModel(

    @SerializedName("token")
    var token: String? = "",

    ...

)
```

Is there any way to tell the retrofit that each endpoint use my base model and also use a specific nested object (as Objects attribute in my base model)

Comment: As far as I know there's no such way to tell retrofit to use different models for the same api. You should check at runtime the response type by using <is> operator: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to parametrise the base class with a generic type. Then reference your case-specific objects when defining Retrofit endpoints.

```
data class APIResultModel<T>(
    @SerializedName("result")
    var result: Boolean? = false,

    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String? = "",

    @SerializedName("objects")
    var objects: T
)
```

Then in Retrofit interface

```
@GET("api/path") 
fun endpoint(): Call<ApiResultModel<UserModel>>
```